# Games aren't running under steam play in ubuntu 20.04.2

Tags: games, steam

So I use Hp elitebook 8570p as my computer and I'm running ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS as my os. My steam doesn't run games using proton trough steam play.

This is the screen that pops up when I start the game:

[image: screenshot]

After that pop up screen comes, steam says that the game is running but the game window isn't coming. After a while steam just says that the game closed. Does anybody have any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: It's a long shot but sometime, after updating nvidia drivers I experience this issue. Rebooting your computer might fix it, allowing Ubuntu to use the latest installed drivers. Also, make sure you're running the latest version of Steam (even try the beta versions) and that you've downloaded the latest Proton version. Sorry if I don't have more insights.

Comment: I would be asking steam support.

Comment: Not all games run under Steam Play / Proton unfortunately. This may be just one of those cases.